# 4 images are load in one scroll in sequencer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

This is plugin's jquery code.in this code one image move in one scroll but my problem is i have to move 4 image one by one in one scroll in this sequencer.
and add specific time interval when one image move to another image please help me out of this problem.

Plugin Demo:https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Image-Sequence-Animation-On-Scroll-Sequencer.html

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.sequencer = function(options, cb) {

    var self = this,
        paths = [],
        load = 0,
        sectionHeight,
        windowHeight,
        currentScroll,
        percentageScroll,
        index;

    if(options.path.substr(-1) === "/") {
      options.path = options.path.substr(0, options.path.length - 1)
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= options.count; i++) {
      paths.push(options.path + "/" + i + "." + options.ext);
    }

    $("<div class='jquery-sequencer-preload'></div>").appendTo("body").css("display", "none");

    $(paths).each(function() {
      $("<img>").attr("src", this).load(function() {
        $(this).appendTo("div.jquery-sequencer-preload");
        load++;
        if (load === paths.length) {
          cb();
        }
      });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      sectionHeight = $(self).height();
      windowHeight = $(this).height();
      currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      percentageScroll = 100 * currentScroll / (sectionHeight - windowHeight);
      index = Math.round(percentageScroll / 100 * options.count);
      if(index < options.count) {
        $("img.sequencer").attr("src", paths[index]);
      }
    });

    return this;

  };

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is `setInterval()`.

You can write a function to change the image which should be pretty simple, and call that function as a parameter in `setInterval()`.

So something along the lines of this at the end of your code:

```
setInterval(changeImage, 60000);
//executes the changeImage() function every 60 seconds
```

You can read more about `setInterval()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

I hope that helps!

Comment: can you please attach you code so i can manage easily to fixed it?